# Android: Issue getting Bluetooth name

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have this method to retrieve the Android device bluetooth name:

```
public String getDeviceName() {
   BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

   if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) return "Unknown device";

   String deviceName = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
   return deviceName;
}
```

It is working properly in most devices, but in a few others I get the device model number, like GT-P1000 (Samsung Galaxy Tab), instead. However, in all devices where I have installed the app, I have changed the device name (Settings -> About device). Any idea? Does this method work whether bluetooth is off?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, my device's name is `LG-D855` which is also its model name. You may be making an assumption about device names which is unfair to make, but I'm also not entirely sure what your problem is.

Comment: When I go to Settings -> About device, the device name is `DEVICE 1` and the model number is `SM-T535`, however with the method above, in some devices I get `DEVICE 1` and in others, `SM-T535`.